# Acess current document in Word interop

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm new to office interop, but I can't for the life of me work out how to get an instance of the Application or Document class that relates to the the word application that is **currently** open (ie not create a new one). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while..maybe there is now a cleaner way without having to use Visual Basic from C Sharp; Using C Sharp with Office Interop has improved recently. I dug this up from very old code, but I use it a lot:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
Application wordApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)Interaction.GetObject(null, "Word.Application");
```

Note the use of null for first parameter `PathName`. Use of empty string would return a new object instance of Word Application. If you omit the `PathName`, `GetObject` will return currently active object.

You may want to wrap in a `try/catch`, and if COM exception occurs, use `CreateObject` (unless these new-fangled programming practices call this bad practice)